# Why am4charts.XYChart ignores date format on some of the values on date axis?

Tags: amcharts

I've set formatting for "hour" period, but some values are always displayed with HH:MM formatting, completely ignoring my settings:

```
dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("hour", "d.M.yyyy\nHH:mm");
```

[image]

I've also tried to set same formatting for all the period types in dateFormats, but nothing changed - some values are always forced to use HH:MM format.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it - I had to disable markUnitChange:

`dateAxis.markUnitChange = false;`

or set also periodChangeDateFormats:

`dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey("hour", "d.M.yyyy\nHH:mm")`;